# Offline-maintenance page has right image, but wrong logo?

Tags: bug, status-completed, logo

Just got smacked in the face with the offline-for-maintenance page (for only one page look, it wasn't long). The sketchy image looks very much like it's designed for Gaming (and is hilarious), but the logo on the top is for Web Applications (again).

Like so
         ↓  ↓

[image: link text]

Comment: very cool image

Comment: I can confirm, got the same thing just a little bit ago.

Comment: This is still there, definitely not completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method of solving this is cute - it now reads "Beta Stack Exchange" on the logo. Now there will definitely be no issues with this issue repeating itself on the different sites.